# Qt sample programs can execute a command line program

Tags: qt

How does make a Qt GUI application which execute a command line program? For example, "go arg1-filename arg2-parameter" can be executed on command line. Let me know sample programs can be referenced for making the Qt GUI application like attached file, to execute the command line program.

[image]

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

```
QProcess process;

//run your command
process.start("your_command arg1 arg2");

//wait for it to finish
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

you can also use it like so:

```
QProcess process;

//run your command
process.start("your_command", QStringList() << "arg1" << "arg2");

//wait for it to finiish.
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

Comment: QProcess is a critical keyword for solving my question. As a result of googling QProcess, good web page like below was found. Thank you. http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QProcess_QFileDialog_QTextEdit_FFmpeg.php

Comment: Hi, xanadev. Yes, it did.

Comment: ah ok, glad it helped :)